# What md5 algorithm does the mongo grid fs used?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I wanted to know if what md5 algorithm we can use that would result in the same md5 that the mongo grid fs can produce.

I actually stored files to mongo using mongo grid fs and in the database, it automatically has the md5 field.

Now because I don't want to store duplicate values I use a hash to hash the file and then compare it to the stored file in the mongo database but comparing it has no use because the md5 hashing I am using does not match to the md5 that mongo grid fs produces.

**Question:**

Any idea?

**md5 algorithm:**

```
 let hash = crypto.createHash('md5').setEncoding('hex');
```

**Sample file 1:**

> md5 value in db using grid fs = `8483931d95617a6ebc8ea6e77f072593`
>
> md5 value using my md5 algo = `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`

Comment: There should be a single MD5 algorithm. Or rather, all MD5 implementations should return the same output for the same input. So, I doubt it's a different *algorithm*, it might just be hashing different data - e.g, entire row or perhaps it adds some sort of "salt" like the ID, or other form of partial row hashing.

Comment: what is that single md5 algorithm sir ? can you provide a link so i can apply

Comment: how can i achieved same md5 result of mongo grid fs

Comment: [MD5 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is a good summary. MD5 is a *specific* hashing algorithm. There can be multiple implementations but they should all have the same result. If they don't, then it's *not MD5* - it's something else. Since the output depends on the *input*, then if you feed MD5 different data, you'd get different results. I don't know what data Mongo hashes but if you are getting different results, then it must be different data.

Comment: The MD5 checksum is computed from the original contents of a user file, however this usage has been deprecated since 2018-01-31 (see the [GridFS specification for more details](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/gridfs/gridfs-spec.rst)). What are your specific versions of MongoDB server & driver? As noted in other comments, MD5 is a standard hashing algorithm so you should be able to calculate the same hash given the same input.

Comment: I already have solve this issue sir thank you.